# Grails run-script with argument

Tags: grails

I want to create grails script which adds an admin account to my application. Something like:

```
grails run-script utils/adminAdd.groovy username password
```

Unfortunately, it seems like *run-script* doesn't support passing arguments to scripts (allowing one to run multiple scripts at once, instead).
Anyone knows a workaround?

Comment: why do you want to add a user via a script? there are several ways to do this: bootstrap, grails console, controller, ...

Comment: And how do you invoke any of them without user interaction (e.g. in a cron job)? Admin management is just an example of issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be supported, so you should create an issue at http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS

In the meantime I think to keep backwards compatibility you probably need a way to differentiate script names from args, e.g. a prefix:

```
grails run-script utils/adminAdd.groovy -Jusername -Jpassword -Jfoo=bar
```

Then `run-script` could split out the args list into un-prefixed script names and send the de-prefixed args to each script as it runs.

Once you get it working locally send a pull request or attach the updated script to the JIRA and it'll get fixed a lot quicker.

Answer (score 0):

See my answer to [How can I run a Groovy class from the command-line within a Grails environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16702218/how-can-i-run-a-groovy-class-from-the-command-line-within-a-grails-environment/19146901#19146901)

In short, you need `includeTargets << grailsScript("_GrailsArgParsing")` in your script; see [documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/commandLine.html) for more options.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still looking for a ready solution, [here it is.](https://gist.github.com/eliasfeijo/41e344c387a8fa199e061f451e4cf51e)

I solved this issue by digging into the grails-2.x/scripts/RunScript.groovy. Then I made myself a new script called RunSingleScript.groovy, which accepts arguments, instead of the original list of scripts.

I believe this code could be re-written to something like what [Burt suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7810322/2644651), and make it part of the core RunScript.groovy. I am lazy, and kind of busy, so I made a custom script which does the job.